# error with Breezyslam (Descriptor length mismatch)

Tags: python, robotics, slam, slam-algorithm

so I was working on a slam project and using the Breezyslam repo [link](https://github.com/simondlevy/BreezySLAM), everytime I run examples or that to check I am getting this error, I don't know where I am getting it wrong, can someone help?

```
File "/home/robopi/Slam/py_slam/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rplidar.py", line 214, in _read_descriptor

raise RPLidarException('Descriptor length mismatch')

rplidar.RPLidarException: Descriptor length mismatch
```

I am using raspberry pi 4 and rplidar A1

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i am getting that error every time i use even after a fresh start (reinstalling raspbian)